# Should be a form 'action' attribute specified for php?

Tags: php, html, forms, superglobals

I want to ask - is the form 'action' attribute necessary for php interpreter?
It's first question. :) I think in most cases i can found all needed data in array $_POST[]

There are few varians of using i have found :

```
action= < ?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>"
action= < ?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
action= < ?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>"
action="FileName.php"
action=""
no 'action' attribute, just 'method' and some other)
```

2. What you think, usage of the first 3 rows (with superglobals) is safely? 
   My English is not so good sometimes :)

Comment: Yes. The answer is yes. Not because of PHP though.

Comment: None of those really matter to the PHP interpreter. The only thing those might matter to is the browser.